# jaxb how to reference an element to http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema like <xs:element ref="xs:schema"/>

Tags: xml, reference, jaxb, schema, genetic

I have this wsdl.  The key point is the line with `<xs:element ref="xs:schema"/>`.  It's an element that refers back to http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.  JAXB does not appear to like it, so I had to import http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema namespace, but I get error (bottom).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="GetSomethingWS" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:getsome="urn://schema.com/services/GetSomething" xmlns:ws="urn://schema.com/services/GetSomething" targetNamespace="urn://schema.com/services/GetSomething">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:getsome="urn://schema.com/services/GetSomething" targetNamespace="urn://schema.com/services/GetSomething" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element name="getSomething" type="getsome:GeneticType"/>
            <xs:complexType name="GeneticType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="xs:schema"/>
                    <xs:any/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getSomething">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="getsome:getSomething"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="GetSomethingWS">
        <wsdl:operation name="getSomething">
            <wsdl:input message="ws:getSomething"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="GetSomethingWSPortBinding" type="ws:GetSomethingWS">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="getSomething">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getSomething" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="GetSomethingWSService">
        <wsdl:port name="GetSomethingWSPort" binding="ws:GetSomethingWSPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://host:port/my.getSomethingWS"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And I attempt to generate Java code using JAXB and ant build script:

```
<project default="wsimport">
<target name="wsimport">
<echo>java home=${java.home}</echo>
<property name="wsdl.path" value="./"/>
<property name="wsdl.name" value="GetSomethingWS.wsdl"/>
<exec executable="${java.home}/../bin/wsimport">
<arg line="-keep -s ./src -p ./ -d ./bin -wsdllocation classpath:${wsdl.path}/${wsdl.name} src/${wsdl.path}/${wsdl.name}" />
</exec>
<copy file = "src/${wsdl.path}/${wsdl.name}" todir="./bin/${wsdl.path}" overwrite="true"/>
</target>
</project>
```

I get these warnings and error:

```
wsimport:
     [echo] java home=C:\SoftwareAG32\jvm\jvm160_32\jre
     [exec] parsing WSDL...
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema'.
     [exec]   line 5 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema'.
     [exec]   line 8 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '12 September 2005'.
     [exec]   line 10 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Table of contents'.
     [exec]   line 13 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Introduction'.
     [exec]   line 15 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Resources'.
     [exec]   line 16 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Introduction'.
     [exec]   line 20 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'This document describes the '.
     [exec]   line 21 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema'.
     [exec]   line 21 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'namespace.
     [exec] It also contains a directory of links to these related resources, using '.
     [exec]   line 22 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Resource Directory Description Language'.
     [exec]   line 23 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '.'.
     [exec]   line 23 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Related Resources for XML Schema'.
     [exec]   line 26 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Schemas for XML Schema'.
     [exec]   line 28 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'DTD'.
     [exec]   line 31 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'A (non-normative) DTD '.
     [exec]   line 32 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XMLSchema.dtd'.
     [exec]   line 32 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'for XML Schema.  It
     [exec] incorporates an auxiliary DTD, '.
     [exec]   line 33 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'datatypes.dtd'.
     [exec]   line 33 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '.'.
     [exec]   line 33 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema'.
     [exec]   line 38 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'An '.
     [exec]   line 39 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema schema document'.
     [exec]   line 39 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'for XML Schema
     [exec] schema documents.  Last updated with release of XML Schema 2nd edition'.
     [exec]   line 40 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'in July 2004.'.
     [exec]   line 41 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Normative References'.
     [exec]   line 48 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema Part 1:
     [exec]           Structures'.
     [exec]   line 53 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '(2nd Edition)'.
     [exec]   line 53 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema Part 2:
     [exec]           Datatypes'.
     [exec]   line 56 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '(2nd Edition)'.
     [exec]   line 56 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'XML Schema Part 0:
     [exec]           Primer'.
     [exec]   line 59 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '(2nd Edition)'.
     [exec]   line 59 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'html' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
     [exec]   line 3 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'html' is not a valid element in a schema document.
     [exec]   line 3 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] src-import.2: The root element of document 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' has to have the namespace name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' and the local name 'schema'.
     [exec]   line 3 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     [exec] [WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xs:schema' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
     [exec]   line 9 of file:/C:/Users/yanja001/Documents/tools/workspace/WsdlValidation/src/GetSomethingWS.wsdl#types?schema1
     [exec] [ERROR] Unexpected <html> appears at line 3 column 135
     [exec]   line 3 of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
```

Is there problem with JAXB or my WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same problem today.

I think you just need to fix your schemaLocation value:

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

(tip - if you go to the location you have currently in the schemaLocation attribute, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", it directs you to the correct url)